# HTML history.pushState isn't working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to make pushState work so I'm testing with a simple HTML page with a single button in it as follows, but it doesn't change the url or seem to do anything.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function(){
    history.pushState({}, '', 'newurl.html');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that code.

I was able to reproduce the problem by trying to load the document directly from my local disk (via a `file:` URL). It gave this error message:

> x.html:9 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///Users/myusername/tmp/fjdkfjkd/newurl.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///Users/myusername/tmp/fjdkfjkd/x.html'.document.getElementById.onclick @ x.html:9

When I loaded the document from a web server (over HTTP), the problem went away.

**You need to load your document from a web server**.

---

There are lots of situations where things behave differently between `file:` and `http:` URLs (including scheme and root relative URLs, XMLHttpRequest, postmessage, and many others). Always do your testing over HTTP to avoid these problems.